# Can't connect to MySQL with C++

Tags: c++, mysql, database

Hello I've been trying to connect a MySQL database with C++ program but every time I try to connect I get error code 0, could someone help me or tell me what am I doing wrong?
Here's my complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SERVER "localhost"
#define USER "user"
#define PASS "password"
#define DATABASE "database"

int main(){

 MYSQL *connect = mysql_init(NULL);
 
 if(!connect){
  std::cout<<"MySQL could not connect\n";
  return 1;
 }
 
 connect = mysql_real_connect(connect, SERVER, USER, PASS, DATABASE, 3306, NULL,0);
 
 if(connect){
  std::cout<<"CONNECTION SUCCESS"<<std::endl;
 }else{
  std::cout<<"CONNECTION FAILED ERROR CODE: "<<mysql_errno(connect)<<std::endl;
 }
 
 return 0;  
}
```

(Yes I've already started the server I guess, and created a specific user for the program)

The output I get is:

> CONNECTION FAILED ERROR: 0

Comment: Instead of using the awful C library, consider using the [C++ adapter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/).

Comment: You are overwriting your value of `connect` so you are losing the ability to locate the proper error value. Try using `if(mysql_real_connect(connect, SERVER, USER, PASS, DATABASE, 3306, NULL,0)) {...}` instead and see if you get a better error message.

Comment: I need the library for the project I want :/

Comment: doing the thing of not rewrite on connect i got error code 1045

Comment: It seems that the error code 1045 it's access denied

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code instead (you will need [Connector/C++](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-downloading.html)):

```
/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' »
   AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
     << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```